# How to subscribe to updates to the root drive of a SharePoint Site using Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I want to subscribe to updates of the root drive of a SharePoint Site using Microsoft Graph.  The problem I am encountering is that when you create a Subscription, you need to provide a resource string.  However, the documentation is very unclear on what this resource string should be for the drive in a SharePoint site.

I tried using this as the resource path:

`sites/{sp-domain},{sp-site-id},{sp-web-id}/drive`

But it is returning a BadRequest.  Have searched everywhere, no useful information in documentation or on the Internet so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the full error details that you are getting. You must be subscribing to the wrong resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this docs on [Supported resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#supported-resources) and this one on [driveItem subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#driveitem), you have to add a path.

Instead of `sites/{sp-domain},{sp-site-id},{sp-web-id}/drive` do `sites/{sp-domain},{sp-site-id},{sp-web-id}/drive/root`. Here is a working HTTP Call

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
{
    "changeType": "updated",
    "notificationUrl": "https://whook-url.com",
    "resource": "sites/SITE-ID/drive/root",
    "expirationDateTime": "2021-09-27T11:59:45.9356913Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientValue",
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I notice that in your example above the resource path though is different than the one you mentioned inline.  Should it be sites/{sp-domain},{sp-site-id},{sp-web-id}/drive/root or sites/SITE-ID/root?  I assume the former?

Comment: Using site-id should be enough, You are right. I corrected the answer. So yes sites/SITE-ID/drive/root

Comment: Thanks - and just to confirm, SITE-ID means {sp-site-id}?  Or {sp-domain},{sp-site-id},{sp-web-id}?  @Danstan

Comment: Site id is the id of the [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). It is the id on the share-point site.

Comment: but in SharePoint online the Site.Id parameter returns a comma separated value that looks like this: {sp-domain},{sp-site-id},{sp-web-id} so I'm trying to understand do I provide this value, or just the sp-site-id?

Comment: Please use what Graph API gives you as the ID as is. Do not look at them as different values. They are what the site-id is and should be used as is and not decoded.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it solves your scenario to help other community users.